# Строковый буфер

Tags: c++

Расскажите мне, пожалуйста, о строковом буфере.

- Что он из себя представляет?
- Для чего нужен?
- Как создается?
- В чем его разница от списка?
- И исходя из кода списка, как его реализовать? Что нужно добавить в список, чтобы превратить его в строковый буфер?

Answer (score 1):

Строковый буфер - это [массив](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2) элементов типа char. [Список](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA) в с++ - это совсем другая структура данных. Что к списку не добавляй - строковый буфер не получится. Можно извлечь элементы из списка и переложить в буфер.

Answer (score 1):

Если под строковым буфером подразумевается некий "буфер", элементами которого являются "строки", то такой буфер (класс) действительно можно сделать на основе списка. Каждый элемент этого списка будет, например содержать тип char* или тип string. Отличаться от обычного списка он будет тем что, например, любой добавляемый в него элемент он должен преобразовывать в тип string. Для этого в нем должны быть реализованы перегруженные методы, которые будут принимать аргументы стандартных типов (int, double, bool, char и т.д.), преобразовывать их в тип string и добавлять их во внутренний список. Следует, наверное, предусмотреть метод вывода всего содержимого этого "буфера". Возможно понадобятся методы произвольного доступа к содержимому (например по индексу или еще как-то)

Comment: То это означает ли, что это будет некий список, в который мы будем добавлять слова, да?
А способ добавления элементов в этот список, будет ли иметь смысл? Откуда они должны добавляются туда? Просто если мы будем вводить вручную, то он не будет отличаться от обычного списка, нет?

Comment: @navi1893, попробуйте написать **как (для чего) Вам нужен** такой буфер. Потом можно обсуждать его устройство.

Comment: Требуется реализовать возможность работы со строками произвольной длины. Сорока хранится отдельными кусками фиксированной длины, которые связаны в список и добавляются или.удаляются по мере.необходимости. Реализация класса должна обладать еще некоторыми свойствами.

Comment: @navi1893, Хотите попробовать реализовать класс [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) ? 

Хорошая тренировка !

Answer (score 1):

Помнится, в книжке С. Пратта "Язык программирования С++" такой класс строится в качестве примера. Можете там посмотреть.